# add mp3 sound using ffmpeg on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm trying to make a mp4 from an app on Android, to do so i added the `FFmpeg` binary.

to create the mp3 i use a command :

```
ffmpegBinaryPath + " -r 24 -i " + inputImgPath + " -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x480 " + outputVideoPath;
```

But i want to add sound on this mp4 i use :

```
ffmpegBinaryPath + " -r 24 -i " + inputImgPath + " -i " + mp3Path + " -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x480 " + outputVideoPath;
```

But it does not work i have no error message and `FFmpeg` stop at the beginning.

I think i need a mp3 code or something like but i can't fin a way to make it works. 
So any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.